# Linux долгая загрузка dev-sda4.device

Tags: linux, boot

[image: график загрузки]

```
systemd-analyze blame 

         19.293s dev-sda4.device
         10.505s grub-common.service
          8.424s networking.service
          8.368s binfmt-support.service
          8.368s console-setup.service
          7.535s irqbalance.service
          6.118s ondemand.service
          5.848s gpu-manager.service
          5.819s systemd-logind.service
          5.808s lm-sensors.service
          5.362s systemd-user-sessions.service
          5.360s rsyslog.service
          5.358s avahi-daemon.service
          4.733s vboxdrv.service
          4.054s NetworkManager.service
          3.357s qemu-kvm.service
          1.586s lvm2-monitor.service
          1.566s systemd-update-utmp.service
          1.421s keyboard-setup.service
          1.183s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.158s thermald.service
          1.125s proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
          1.007s mnt-A01A17331A1705C6.mount
           969ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           888ms systemd-modules-load.service
           777ms systemd-udevd.service
           764ms resolvconf.service
           734ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           713ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           706ms systemd-journald.service
           696ms udisks2.service
           681ms colord.service
           642ms dev-mqueue.mount
           642ms dev-hugepages.mount
           637ms alsa-restore.service
           620ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5-18.mount
           611ms packagekit.service
           572ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5-13.mount
           537ms snap-core-4486.mount
           512ms snap-core-4571.mount
           494ms snap-core-4650.mount
           485ms dev-loop0.device
           477ms upower.service
           447ms pppd-dns.service
           438ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           432ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           428ms systemd-random-seed.service
           399ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5-16.mount
           381ms dev-loop5.device
           356ms setvtrgb.service
           355ms dev-loop4.device
           334ms dev-loop3.device
           321ms dev-loop1.device
           319ms polkitd.service
           304ms systemd-sysctl.service
           286ms sddm.service
           278ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           261ms rc-local.service
           183ms vboxweb-service.service
           183ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
           183ms vboxautostart-service.service
           177ms rtkit-daemon.service
           162ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
           157ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           152ms dev-loop2.device
           139ms ufw.service
            66ms user@1000.service
            53ms tmp.mount
            10ms plymouth-quit.service
            10ms plymouth-read-write.service
             4ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
             2ms ureadahead-stop.service
             1ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
           935us sys-kernel-config.mount

systemd-analyze
    graphical.target @18.472s
    └─multi-user.target @18.472s
      └─grub-common.service @7.966s +10.505s
        └─basic.target @7.926s
          └─sockets.target @7.926s
            └─cups.socket @7.926s
              └─sysinit.target @7.751s
                └─systemd-update-utmp.service @6.185s +1.566s
                  └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @5.663s +432ms
                    └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.928s +734ms
                      └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.343s +157ms
                        └─system.slice @2.102s
                      └─-.slice @1.903s
```

Общее время загрузки 70сек! Параллельно установлен windows 10, который загружается быстрее.

С чем связано? Раньше загружалось раза в 2 быстрее... Да, и, кстати, данную систему сохранял и восстанавливал с помощью acronis true image на новое железо, это как то могло повлиять на данную ситуацию? Диск на ошибки проверял, всё нормально, смарт давно не смотрел, но, по ощущению, вроде не умирает пока.

Comment: возможно, в `/etc/fstab` для этого раздела указан некорректный *uuid*. сравните с выводом `$ sudo blkid`

Comment: Да хз, походу проблема в самом диске, сейчас установил manjaro с нуля (на тотже раздел правда, отформатировав предварительно), общее время загрузки примерно одинаковое получается.

Comment: Раздел закриптован?